# virtualenv gives error after upgrade of setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I update setuptools from 0.6c11 to 1.1 after getting versionConflict Error.

Now when i am doing:

```
virtualenv -q /var/lib/jenkins/env
```

it is giving me OS error.

Here is traceback report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.8.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 942, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1052, in create_environment
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 599, in install_setuptools
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 571, in _install_req
    cwd=cwd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1020, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /var/lib/jenkins/env/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])

" /usr/local/lib/pytho...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg failed with error code 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```